# How can I build a jar (with all it's dependencies) in maven?

Tags: maven, jar, jar-with-dependencies

I have a custom appliction, build in maven, with dependencies (more custom modules, and some other things like spring, apache commons and log4j).

How can I build an executable jar containing my application and all of it's dependencies? (I.e. what do I need to put in my `pom.xml`)

I am aware that it will be several megabytes in size, but I am looking for simplicity in building and executing my application.

And I would like to build via standard `mvn clean install` command.

Answer (score 1):

Check out maven shade plugin. https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/